# android how to build the apk that works for android 2.3 as minimum os level

Tags: java, android, operating-system, apk, platform

This is how my manifest file look like

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

when I right click on android project > properties > android I see target name as android 4.0 as minimum

I want to make the apk file usable in android 2.3 platform

features and API I am using:

- google maps v2, fused location provider

I am fairly new to android, I did google before asking

Comment: What specifically is your problem?

Comment: how do I make sure that app is going to run in 2.3

Comment: I'd start by trying it on an Android 2.3 device. There's nothing in what you have described here that would suggest it will not work in Android 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is Targeted on Android version having API 17 but your app is supported to GB(GingerBread 2.3.x) By mentioning the minimum API level to 10 your app is supposed to be run in 2.3.x . And  as long as you keep using [support libary](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) all features can be utilized on GB such as Fragments,ActionBar

```
Tip:
```

To utilize all the features without getting any pain in head use the latest Compiler eg: API 20 and target to those devices which are currently runnung(API 19)

Answer (score 0):

Download the SDK using SDK manager and change that to android 2.3.x and verify in project.properties file "target" value is updated properly.

if you are selecting 2.3.3 then target in project.properties file will be 
target=android-10

change the "android:minSdkVersion" as per the target selected, in above case it looks like 
android:minSdkVersion=10

clean and build the project. After that you are good to go.

Comment: This is not required to support Android 2.3.